# How to change inline bot handler in Telegram

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot) and created a telegram bot. I enabled inline mode and created inline query handler using this code:

```
from telegram import InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent
def inline_caps(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    if not query:
        return
    results = list()
    results.append(
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=query.upper(),
            title='Caps',
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(query.upper())
        )
    )
    context.bot.answer_inline_query(update.inline_query.id, results)

from telegram.ext import InlineQueryHandler
inline_caps_handler = InlineQueryHandler(inline_caps)
dispatcher.add_handler(inline_caps_handler)
```

I numerous times I tried to change this inline query handler, but nothing works. This doesn't work:

dispatcher.[remove_handler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html#telegram.ext.Dispatcher.remove_handler)(inline_caps_handler)

I also tried to diable inline mode and then enable it again using BotFather, but the old handler still stays untouched in site of reactivating inline mode.

Creating a new handler and adding it doesn't work also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you give it another try?

I followed the tutorial (up to "dispatcher.add_handler(inline_caps_handler)") and it gave me no problem.
After done playing with caps, I did dispatcher.remove_handler(inline_caps_handler) and it stopped converting to uppercase the words I write. Then I added another handler (a lowercase converter) and the bot was updated.

Here is the example I'm running in the Python interactive shell (which is pretty similar to the tutorial but trimmed the non-inline stuff):

```
from telegram.ext import Updater
updater = Updater(token='TOKEN', use_context=True)

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                     level=logging.INFO)

updater.start_polling()

from telegram import InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent
def inline_caps(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    if not query:
        return
    results = list()
    results.append(
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=query.upper(),
            title='Caps',
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(query.upper())
        )
    )
    context.bot.answer_inline_query(update.inline_query.id, results)

from telegram.ext import InlineQueryHandler
inline_caps_handler = InlineQueryHandler(inline_caps)
dispatcher.add_handler(inline_caps_handler)

dispatcher.remove_handler(inline_caps_handler)
def inline_lower(update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    if not query:
        return
    results = list()
    results.append(
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=query.lower(),
            title='lows',
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(query.lower())
        )
    )
    context.bot.answer_inline_query(update.inline_query.id, results)

from telegram.ext import InlineQueryHandler
inline_lower_handler = InlineQueryHandler(inline_lower)
dispatcher.add_handler(inline_lower_handler)
```

And after finishing testing.

```
updater.stop()
```